# Swift: how to create a convenience init for UIAlertController with no parameters

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, convenience-methods

I am trying to create a `convenience init` with no parameters for a subclassed `UIAlertController`, but it is giving me an error.

It gives me this error:

**Use of self in delegating initializer before self.init is called**

```
class AvatarSelectionAlert: UIAlertController {

    convenience init(test: String) {
        let title = NSLocalizedString("ALERT_CHOOSE_AVATAR_TITLE", comment: "")
        let message = NSLocalizedString("ALERT_CHOOSE_AVATAR_MESSAGE", comment: "")
        self.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let selectPremadeAvatarAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("SELECT_PREMADE_AVATAR", comment: ""), style: .Default) { Void in

        }
        addAction(selectPremadeAvatarAction)

        let chooseFromGalleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("CHOOSE_FROM_GALLERY", comment: ""), style: .Default) { Void in

        }
        addAction(chooseFromGalleryAction)

        let takeNewPictureAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("TAKE_NEW_PICTURE", comment: ""), style: .Default) { Void in

        }
        addAction(takeNewPictureAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { Void in
        }
        addAction(cancelAction)
    }
}
```

I have also tried to call `self.init()` before calling the other `self.init`, but it crashes.

Is it possible to create a `convenience init` with no parameters?

Comment: check if you method self.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet) is calling super.init?

Comment: Updated with my full method. When I call `self.init()` before the other `self.init(title, message, style)` it crashes on the self.init() line

Comment: Yes you can to create a convenience init with no parameters.

Comment: @Prabhu.Somasundaram I get a runtime error if i add `self.init()` before the other initializer

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to achieve in subclassing UIAlertController?

#### Subclassing Notes

The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.[Refer here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014538-CH1-SW4)

Answer (score 0):

Just do the extension of UIAlertController.

```
extension UIAlertController {

    public convenience init?(test: String) {
        let title = NSLocalizedString("ALERT_CHOOSE_AVATAR_TITLE", comment: "")
        let message = NSLocalizedString("ALERT_CHOOSE_AVATAR_MESSAGE", comment: "")
        self.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let selectPremadeAvatarAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("SELECT_PREMADE_AVATAR", comment: ""), style: .default) { Void in

        }
        addAction(selectPremadeAvatarAction)

        let chooseFromGalleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("CHOOSE_FROM_GALLERY", comment: ""), style: .default) { Void in

        }
        addAction(chooseFromGalleryAction)

        let takeNewPictureAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("TAKE_NEW_PICTURE", comment: ""), style: .default) { Void in

        }
        addAction(takeNewPictureAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { Void in
        }
        addAction(cancelAction)
    }

}
```